# c# KeyUpEvent occurs before KeyDownEvent

Tags: c#, winforms

### Edit

Ok I think I got the problem. I forgot that I hook the keyUpEvent Globally.
Since the global key events are processed first this phenomenon can occur.

### Original

I got a little problem. The keyup event occurs before the keydown event.

What my program shall do is:
while the user is pressing a key, the microphone input is being recorded.
When the user releases the key recording is stopped and the wav file is being saved.

If the user is pressing one key after another everything is fine.
But pressing several keys in a short period of time results in the above explained behaviour.
I added some code so that I can see what happens. This is the output of such a case.

```
Key down NumPad4, NumPad4, 100
128 = KeyDownTime
Key up NumPad4, NumPad4, 100
117 = KeyUpTime
Key up NumPad5, NumPad5, 101
0 = KeyUpTime
Key up NumPad6, NumPad6, 102
0 = KeyUpTime
Key down NumPad5, NumPad5, 101
58 = KeyDownTime
Key down NumPad6, NumPad6, 102
0 = KeyDownTime
```

as you can see the keyup events of numpad5 and numpad6 occured earlier than their keydown event.
Can it happen that 2 events arise but the second finishes earlier ? 
I thought about delaying the leyup event with thread.sleep for like 50 ms.
But I hope that there is a better solution.

I didn't add any code because it is trivial and I don't know what may help you helping me.
But if you need to see it just tell me which part I shall post.

Edit here is a part of the code: Here the KeyDownEvent

```
private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Key down"+e.KeyCode.ToString() + ", " + e.KeyData.ToString() + ", " + e.KeyValue.ToString()+"\n");
            StWt1 = new Stopwatch();
            StWt1.Start();
            try
            {                
                if (ready && !keyPressed)
                {
                    switch (e.KeyData)
                    {
                        case Keys.D0:
                            keyPressed = true;
                            calib = 10.0;
                            calib2 = mySaver.ID;
                            adjustLabelDisplay(10);
                            break;
                            // this is all the same with different value for calib depending on the pressed key
                        case Keys.Decimal:
                            keyPressed = true;
                            calib = 100.0;
                            calib2 = mySaver.ID;
                            adjustLabelDisplay(100);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (!ready)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Missing at least one calibration value!");
                    labelDisplay.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    labelDisplay.Text = "--------";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.Visible = true;
                buttonHideRTB.Visible = true;
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Exception:\n");
                if (e == null)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Eventargs are Zero");
                if (sender == null)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Sender is null");
                if (calib == null)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("calib is null");
                if (calib2 == null)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("calib2 is null");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Exception Message: " + ex.Message + "\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Exception source: " + ex.Source + "\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Exception Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Exception Traget Site: " + ex.TargetSite + "\n");
                MessageBox.Show("Exception was thrown. Check The Rich Text Box for further information.");
            }
            richTextBox1.AppendText(StWt1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " = KeyDownTime\n");
            StWt1.Stop();
        }
```

The Method that is called by KeyDownevent in the switch section:

```
private void adjustLabelDisplay(int x)
        {
            calib_ValueChangedEvent();
            calib2_ValueChangedEvent();
            currentKey = x;
            labelDisplay.Text = "Key: " + x;
            labelDisplay.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,128,0);
            this.labelDisplay.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            if (labelCB1.Text[0] != x.ToString()[0])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Change to working page!");
            }
            if (checkBoxMode.Checked)
                enhRec.startRec();
            else
            {
                recorder.startRecordVoice();
                startTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

and the keyUpEvent:

```
private void UserControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Key up" + e.KeyCode.ToString() + ", " + e.KeyData.ToString() + ", " + e.KeyValue.ToString()+"\n");
            StWt2 = new Stopwatch();
            StWt2.Start();
            if (ready)
            {
                if (keyPressed)
                {
                    calib2=0;
                    calib=0;
                    labelCB1.Text = "0";
                    labelCB2.Text = "0";
                    keyPressed = false;
                    labelDisplay.Text = "Key: ";
                    labelDisplay.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255);
                    this.labelDisplay.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
                    if (checkBoxMode.Checked)
                        enhRec.saveRec(getSaveString());
                    else
                        recorder.stopRecordVoice(getSaveString(), startTime, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                labelDisplay.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                labelDisplay.Text = "Key: ";
            }
            richTextBox1.AppendText(StWt2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " = KeyUpTime\n");
            StWt2.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: i use winforms and it is a usercontrol

Comment: The order in which these events occur is well-defined, see [MSDN documentation for KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) - it's `KeyDown`, then `KeyPress`, then `KeyUp`. You're doing something wrong. Show us some code.

Comment: Yeah the order is defined but this needn't mean that they finish at the sam time, or nor ? And why does it work if i press the keys normal or fast (not hyper fast ^^). But I will post the 2 events

Comment: Probably the following event will not be raised until the previous event and its handlers finish its execution.

Comment: Override WndProc and you will see the raw, definitive data. This'll show you exactly what messages come in at which times in which order.

Answer (score 0):

You're using global state (the `keyPressed` member) to store keyboard state information. In your code **any** `KeyUp` event will stop your recording session. This means you can press one key (start recording), then press another key and release it, while still holding the first key, and your recording will stop.

Comment: was this a question or an answer? but yes this it what will happen in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken these events are handled in two different places, which explains why the faster the keys are pressed the more sporadic the results become. You see, the control handling the `KeyUp` event has no handler for the `KeyDown` event so as the message pump starts coming in you're going to get the `KeyUp` events before the `KeyDown` events because some of the `KeyDown` events are waiting for others to finish.

It's a race condition.

Handle the events in a single class and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh sorry, no this is the same I just wrote another name so that it corresponds to the text forgot it in the other one. I ll change it.

Comment: @lorenzalbert, so you are ___not___ handling these events in two different places? In other words one is attached inside the user control's code behind and the other is attached on the form?

Comment: No both are in the same UserControl. Actually it is no UserControl but a control that inherits from UserControl. but that shouldn't be the problem.